# LESS CSS: put cookieless domainname in a variable for reuse in background:url()

Tags: variables, less, cookieless

I'd like to set my cookieless domain in a variable and reuse it for background images like this:

```
@static_url: "//static.example.com";
.background {background:url(@static_url/images/layout/sprite-icn.png) no-repeat;}
```

but my LESS compiler (lesscss-engine-1.3.0.jar) throws an error cause of these lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was:

```
@static_url: "//static.example.com";
.background {background:url("@{static_url}/images/layout/sprite-icn.png") no-repeat;}
```